# Is expression "It does us no harm." grammatically correct?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, prepositional-phrases, indirect-objects, predicate-frames, dative-alternation

I would write it with *"to"*:

*"It does to us no harm."*

or

*"It does no harm to us"*.

Similar example from https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/do-to

*"I’ll never forgive him for what he **did to me**."*

Comment: Why do you think "it does us no harm" is grammatically incorrect? Just because there are multiple ways of wording something, doesn't make any of them ungrammatical.

Comment: SEE ALSO: "Smoking never did anyone any good", as well as many another flavor of *to do someone something*.

Answer (score 2):

"It does us no harm" is grammatical. Both *do one harm* and *do one good* are used in English as idiomatic expressions.

There are a number of expressions in English where a "dative" or "indirect object" is not required to be marked with the preposition "to". A common example is sentences with the verb *give,* as in "They gave us our presents". "It does us no harm" has the same syntax.

This may be called "[dative alternation](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Dative_alternation)" or "dative shift". As other answers have mentioned, the usual word order when "to" is used would be "It does no harm to us", not "It does to us no harm". But for this expression, using "to" is not as idiomatic.

Comment: "Give us this day ..."

Comment: I'm thinking that *"He did me wrong"* just might **not** be subject to dative alternation like most(?) others are, but I have no idea why not.

Answer (score 0):

"To do no harm" (or "to do [someone] no harm") [is a very very old phrase,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+no+harm%2Cdoes+no+harm%2Cdo+him+no+harm) at least for a language that evolves as quickly as English. Here it is [in Macbeth, written in 1606 (line 69).](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/macbeth/page_152.html) I don't have a lot of evidence for this, but I believe that this phrase doesn't seem to follow modern grammar rules simply because it is so old.

So, you should never add another "to" in front of the person it's affecting. However, if you really want to, you *can* put that phrase at the end.

So,

> "It does **to us** no harm" = sounds really weird; never say this
>
> "It does no harm **to us**" = fine; you can use this

I'm not sure if there's an actual grammatical reason for this, but I can tell you I've never once heard a native English speaker say it the first way. It's a pattern followed in several other places.

For example,

> "It makes sense **to me**" = fine
>
> "It makes **to me** sense" = sounds very weird and wrong

Edit: for a more detailed/grammatical explanation, listen to sumelic.